# No option to run JUNIT test in VSC?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, junit

I've done quite a bit of research on this and i'm pretty sure I have all the requirements and for certain all the extensions. However, I'm still not seeing any option to click "run test" above my @Test method?

I have not set up the conventional file structure yet, I'm just experimenting with JUNIT with a single java file trying to test a method.

Here is my VSC settings.json where I added references to jar files as per the VSC guide I read.
[image]

and this is the code I'm trying to test
[image]

I don't see any option to run my @Test method, i would appreciate any pointers. Thanks

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing I am sure you never enabled this extension.

Comment: @hfontanez Java Extension Pack from Microsoft, Java Dependency Viewer from Microsoft, Debugger for Java from Microsoft, Java Test Runner from Microsoft, Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat, are all installed and enabled..

Comment: there seems to be a problem with how I've referenced the jar files in settings.json because I'm receiving the error "error: package org.junit does not exist" for my import statements.

Comment: That should've been in your problem description. You may have a corrupt VSC install.

Comment: @Knightly Could you find the `Testing Explorer` on the left-side Activity bar of VSCode?